# Nodejs ,mongoose is not fetching data from mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Please find the code of app.js
var express = require('express'), routes = require('./routes');

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

// Configuration

app.configure(function(){

  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

  app.set('view engine', 'jade');

  app.use(express.bodyParser());

  app.use(express.methodOverride());

  app.use(app.router);

  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));   });

app.configure('development', function(){

  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));

});

app.configure('production', function(){

  app.use(express.errorHandler());  });

// Routes

app.get('/', routes.index);

app.listen(3000, function(){

  console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", 

 app.address().port, app.settings.env); });


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mydb', function (error) {

    if (error) {

    console.log(error);

    }

});

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({

    first_name: String,

    last_name: String,

    email: String

});

// Mongoose Model definition

var User = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);


app.get('/', function (req, res) {

    res.send("<a href='/users'>Show Users</a>");

});

app.get('/users', function (req, res) {

    User.find({}, function (err, docs) {

    res.json(docs);

    });

});

app.get('/users/:email', function (req, res) {

    if (req.params.email) {

    User.find({ email: req.params.email }, function (err, docs) {

        res.json(docs);

    });

    }

});
```

Mongodb is running and in mydb and inside collection below document is present
{ "_id" : ObjectId("562101187941ab21a444c286"), "first_name" : "u1", "last_name"

: "u1", "email" : "an@ii.com" }

But when i run nodejs app.js and connect to http://localhost:3000/users it shows [] and not the data in database. Please help

Comment: what is `routes.index`?

Comment: Its an index.jade file in route folder to display HTML

Comment: Is your collection called 'users'?

Comment: No. but if i change var User = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);
to var User = mongoose.model('collection1', UserSchema); but also no output. "collection1" is the name of my collection in db

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your collection **should** be named "users" for mongoose to find it. 
Mongoose normally save collections with plural names, adding "s" to model names.
Since your model name is already plural it should be named "users".

Comment: My collection name is users only in db, but also not getting the data on web page